# Run a hava program from gradle as a part of another task

Tags: gradle

I can run a java program as a separate gradle task using `JavaExec` type for the task:

```
task (foo, type: JavaExec) {
    main = '...'
    ...
}
```

However, how do I run a Java program as a *part* of another task, say in a `doLast`? I can probably do something with ant executor, but is there some way more native to gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a dependency with `dependsOn` between tasks or you can use `javaexec` method defined on project instance, see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#javaexec(org.gradle.api.Action)).

Pseudocode:

```
task t {
   doLast {
      javaexec {
       //logic goes here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I knew about `dependsOn`, but it seems I need to instrument classes as part of compilation task, as otherwise incremental compilation doesn't work since "output files have changed".

Comment: Sure, so `javaexec` closure should be what you're looking for.